# bash script: find max, group by and sort by column

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file that looks like this:

```
b, 20, 434
a, 20, 23
a, 10, 123
a, 20, 423
a, 10, 89
b, 20, 88
b, 10, 133
b, 10, 99
```

1. Find the max of col 3 for every unique combination of col1 and col2. (e.g. max of col3 for all `a,10`)
2. Group the output by col1 (all `a` rows together)
3. Sort the output by col2.

That is, the output should be 
file should be

```
a, 10, 123
a, 20, 423
b, 10, 133
b, 20, 434
```

How can I do this in a bash script?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will slightly modify the whitespace, but perhaps that is acceptable:

```
awk '$3 > a[$1,$2] { a[$1,$2] = $3 } END {for( k in a) print k a[k]}' input |
    sort -n -t, -k1,1 -k2,2
```

But that solution is highly dependent on the whitespace in the input, so it would probably be better to do something like:

```
awk '$3 > a[$1","$2] { a[$1","$2] = $3 } 
    END {for( k in a) print k "," a[k]}' FS=, input |
    sort -n -t, -k1,1 -k2,2
```

Comment: The `awk` portion selects the max of column 3 for rows in which columns 1 and 2 match, and the sort sorts by column1 first, and then column2.

Comment: Typo in your second code block `a[$","$2] = $3` should be `a[$1","$2] = $3`.

Comment: above command treats array elements as strings i think. can i force it to treat them as numbers? Issue is that "a, 40, 99" appears after "a, 100, 99".

Comment: @KVM Yes, add `-n` to the sort.

Answer (score 5):

This does the job:

```
< input sort -k3,3gr | sort -k1,1 -k2,2g -u
```

It sorts numerically in reverse order on the third field and then sorts on the first and second field taking just the first occurrence (-u for unique).

You do not need padding, i.e. if you add to the input a line like

```
a, 3, 31
```

The output is:

```
a, 3, 31
a, 10, 123
a, 20, 423
b, 10, 133
b, 20, 434
```

Comment: what is `< input` at the very beginning?

Comment: try to check this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106039/why-does-the-less-than-sign-not-work-as-a-replacement-for-cat-in-bash